# ¿Cómo hacer que el valor del input se pase al swicth?

Tags: javascript

Soy nueva en JavaScript, y tengo el problema que cuando escribo en el input la opcion 1, no sale el alert del caso 1 del switch. ¿Alguien sabe por qué el valor no se está pasando al switch?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Switch</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
      Ingrese una opcion: <input type="number" name="opcion" id="opcion"><br>
      <button onclick="Opcion(document.getElementById('opcion').value)">Enter</button>
    </form>

    <script  type="text/javascript">

      function Opcion(opcion) {

        switch (opcion) {
              case 1:
              alert ("Opcion 1")
                break;
              case 2:
              alert ("Opcion 2")
                break;     
             }     
      }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En ocasiones el navegador puede entregar un string o un int, como tu esperas un int debes manipular el valor en el switch de esta forma

```
console.log(opcion); //Con esto puedes ver en consola que tipo de dato trae
switch (parseInt(opcion)) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tendras que parsear a Int o colocar el case como string:

```js
function Opcion(opcion) {

  switch (opcion) {
    case '1':
      alert("Opcion 1")
      break;
    case '2':
      alert("Opcion 2")
      break;
      default: console.log("Error");
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Switch</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    Ingrese una opcion: <input type="number" name="opcion" id="opcion"><br>
    <button onclick="Opcion(document.getElementById('opcion').value)">Enter</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

AL margen de que ya tienes 2 respuestas que solucionan tu problema me gustaría aportar el siguiente ejemplo:

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Switch</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          Ingrese una opcion: <input type="text" name="opcion" id="opcion"><br>
          <button id="btn">Enter</button>
    
        <script>
    
            let boton  = document.getElementById("btn")
          
            boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
              let opcion = document.getElementById("opcion").value;
              ((elemento) => {
                switch (elemento) {
                  case '1':
                    alert("1")
                    break;
                  case '2':
                    alert("2")
                    break;
                    default: alert("Opción no válida");
                }
              })(opcion)
            })
            </script>
        </body>
    
    </html>
```

Donde:

- Sacamos la lógica de tu ejercicio de JS de las etiquetas HTML y en su lugar obtenemos tanto el valor del `input` como del botón por medio de su id
- Les agregamos un *listener* al botón para identificar cuando el usuario le da click
- Usamos una función por dentro del tipo [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) a la cual solo le pasaremos al final entre parentesis la variable que contiene el valor que tecleo el usuario y recuperamos mas arriba